Correct syntax for whole array initializaition
Why is the following an error and what is the correct syntax?
struct a {
    int b[4];
};

int c[4];
struct a a = {.b = &c};

Shouldn't a.b be of type int * or int[], why is it of type int?
(Note, that the declaration of struct a can't be changed.)

You can't initialize one array from another unfortunately. a.b is of type int[4] which is different from int *.

"Shouldn't a.b be of type int * or int[], why is it of type int?" Yes, it is one of your 2 options. But you seem to think, that they are the same, which they are not. You use it as if it was int* but you defined it as int[]. And a.b is not of type int. Where do you get that idea from?

@Gerhardh I got that idea from my compiler.

You must provide an initializer list: struct a a = { .b={1, 2, 3, 4}}; You cannot initialize an array with a pointer (i.e. the address of another array).

Then please show the complete and exact error message. I am sure it will not tell you it is int.

@Gerhardh warning: initialization of 'int' from 'int (*)[4]' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Interesting. It seems to treat &c as intializer for b[0] which is an int.

@Gerhardh I appended an explanation about that to my posted answer.

@Gerhardh: Yes, and Clang accepts struct a a = {.b = 3, 4}; and sets a.b[0] to 3 and a.b[1] to 4. That is because, when you are initializing an aggregate, you are allowed to omit braces for subobjects, just listing the values as a flat list. E.g., you can have struct { struct { int f, g, h[3]; } } x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; instead of … { { 1, 2, { 3, 4, 5 } } };. So .b = just sets the current object of initializing to the b member, and then processing picks up from there, automatically going into its subobjects.

@EricPostpischil thanks. I was not aware that this also applies when you use dedicated initializers. For me this is a bit surprising but well, this is C. ;)

@Gerhardh: GCC and Clang have -Wmissing-braces to warn if braces are not fully used, but Clang seems to miss it if the array is the only member in the structure, whereas GCC warns.

The C language is a bit weird since for historical reasons it does not allow initialization or assignment between two arrays. That's just how the language is defined.
C does however allow structs to be initialized/assigned from other structs of the same type. Even if they happen to contain an array. So you could do this:
struct a c = { .b = {1,2,3,4} };
...
struct a a = c;

Or otherwise skip initialization and use run-time assignment instead. Since we're dealing with arrays we can't use = but have to use memcpy:
int c[4] = {1,2,3,4};
struct a a;
memcpy(a.b, c, sizeof(a.b));


As for the reason for the peculiar compiler error:

warning: initialization of 'int' from 'int (*)[4]' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Initialization of arrays (or structs) is done by the compiler internally keeping track on the current object to initialize. When we type in a designated initializer .b, the compiler sets the current object to be initialized to the first item b[0] in the array b. And then expects a number of initializers with type int from there on. For each int we hand it in the initializer list, it will automatically shift current initialized object to the next one in the list, b[1], b[2] and so on.
If written properly that would look like .b = {1,2,3,4} but the braces are actually optional. What matters is the compiler keeping track of the current object. We could as well write sloppy code like .b = 1,2,3,4. Very bad practice but valid C.
Anyway, since the compiler expects an int but is given a pointer to array with &c, it raises a constraint violation diagnostic message. It expected an int but got a int (*)[4] and that is invalid C.
.b = something is fine as far as the syntax is concerned, the types just didn't match in case of .b = &c. The types are regulated by the constraints of the assignment operator. A compiler must give a diagnostic message whenever the code violates either the C syntax or the C constraints.

In practice, struct a is used as an output parameter and I first thought, that it was declared (as a/ like a) pointer and tried to make it write to somewhere different.

@Caulder .b = c would just produce a different flavour of the same warning, "expected int got int[4]" or something like that. Since an array isn't a valid initializers here. It's weird but that's just how it is.

Are there advantages of not allowing array from array initialization or is it just a missing feature? Are there plans to change that in C2Y?

@Caulder: It would be disruptive to change this now. Current C parsing requires the array A in struct foo { int *p; } x = { A }; to be converted to a pointer, which correctly initializes the int *p. If initializing arrays with arrays were supported, the compiler would have to handle both this and struct foo { int p[3]; } x = { A };. That would require it to decide whether to convert A to a pointer or keep it as an array based on internal details of the type foo, possibly several levels deep in the type…

… And consider struct { void *p[3]; } x = { A };, where A is an array of void *. This initialization could be either p is initialized to a copy of A or p[0] is initialized to the result of converting A to a pointer to its first element. There are likely additional complications and ramifications too.

Should make it clear that struct a a = c; (where c is a struct a) is only valid when a is defined to have automatic storage class.

You are correct in your assessment: b should have type int * or int const * but you should drop the & from the initializer:
struct a {
    int *b;
};

int c[4];
struct a a = { .b = c };

Or equivalently:
struct a a = { c };


But the declaration of a.b is exactly as given in my question.

@Caulder no, in your question you have int b[4]; which is very different from int *b;. Arrays are not pointers.

@chqrlie I know, hence my question, how to initialize the array. I can't change the declaration of struct a, because it is declared in a library.

However declaring a struct which contains nothing but a pointer to data allocated elsewhere likely does make no sense to use.
